# How to add new elements to the end of a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I wrote some Python code that save a dictionary of dictionaries in a JSON file and I would like to add more dictionaries (inside the main dictionary) at the end of the file without having to load and rewrite it all.

Here is an example, my initial file look like this:

```
{ "dict1": {"key1": 1.1, "key2": 1.2}, "dict2": {"key1": 2.1 "key2": 2.2}}
```

And I want to add `"dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}` to it:

```
{ "dict1": {"key1": 1.1, "key2": 1.2}, "dict2": {"key1": 2.1 "key2": 2.2}, "dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}}
```

I tried to open the file in `"a"` mode but it don't work because of the closing `}`. So is there any way to overwrite just the last character of my file or a smarter way to get the same result?

Comment: Why don't you want to load json in memory and write updated json?

Comment: Doing this in general generic way could get trickly. However if you know the structure of the JSON file in advance, just copy everything in the file before the final `}` character, add what you want (with a leading comma for what's in your example), and then write the final `}`.

Comment: @Budulianin Because I will have to repeat this process many time and the file will become a bit huge (I expect some Go) so I would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: @martineau Interesting idea, I am currently using json.dump() to write my files and I don't know exactly how many iteration but I think it is no big deal to change this to do as you said. if there is no better solution I will do it like this

Comment: @Gabriel Are you sure that simple load json is not enough? I think, that if your task would to need optimization you will be aware how implement your solution.

Comment: @Budulianin I am sure that simple load will be too long because even if I am prototyping alone a little project, I work on a huge databse and execution time is important for my prototype so I am trying my best to optimize the most time consuming steps of my code

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" [someone smart once said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: @Gabriel You can choose another way to store your dicts. Any special and fast DB because your way using JSON file is weird.

Comment: @martineau I will keep this smart advice in mind but I don't like the idea of having to load a file bigger than my RAM many times just to add a few lines at the end

Comment: @Budulianin I get my data with pymongo from a MongoDB, I found that saving it as JSON file very convenient at the beginning but if you have any better suggestions I will be very intersted to hear them

Comment: Unless you know the structure of the file in advance, you may have no choice.

Comment: @martineau If I have no choice I will do as you suggest and be careful with that fact that when I put the ending `}` there is no way to add more elements without loading everything

Comment: Off-hand, not that I can think of that would be able to handle every possible valid JSON file. However, as I suggested, if you know the structure of the JSON in the files you're processing, then you should be able do something relatively simple and specific to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing a data file in place is a bit tricky and dangerous. You have to patch up the original file format just so. Often it's simpler to just read the whole file's JSON, add the data item, then re-serialize and rewrite the file. But, for performance and other reasons, hot-patching is sometimes what the doctor ordered. So:

```py
def append_to_json(filepath, data):
    """
    Append data in JSON format to the end of a JSON file.
    NOTE: Assumes file contains a JSON object (like a Python
    dict) ending in '}'. 
    :param filepath: path to file
    :param data: dict to append
    """

    # construct JSON fragment as new file ending
    new_ending = ", " + json.dumps(data)[1:-1] + "}\n"

    # edit the file in situ - first open it in read/write mode
    with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:

        f.seek(0, 2)        # move to end of file
        index = f.tell()    # find index of last byte

        # walking back from the end of file, find the index 
        # of the original JSON's closing '}'
        while not f.read().startswith('}'):
            index -= 1
            if index == 0:
                raise ValueError("can't find JSON object in {!r}".format(filepath))
            f.seek(index)

        # starting at the original ending } position, write out
        # the new ending
        f.seek(index)
        f.write(new_ending)    

# let 'er rip
newval = {"dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}}
append_to_json('data.json', newval)
```

Assuming the original data is in `data.json`, after running this the file will contain:

```
{ "dict1": {"key1": 1.1, "key2": 1.2}, 
  "dict2": {"key1": 2.1, "key2": 2.2}, 
  "dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}}
```

(JSON output here has been aligned for easier reading. In the file, it will likely be one extremely long line.)

Note, I've kept this simple so it's easier to follow and understand. In practice, there is a second kind of JSON file you will often encounter: the record-oriented file, which is an array of objects (`[ {}, ... {}]`).  That style ends with a ']' not '}'. A more-developed version of this routine would look for that case too.

Comment: Thx you ! I think it's is esxactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should build one giant JSON string. If it's really **"bigger than my RAM"**, then how are you going to later **use** it anyway?

I suggest you use a proper database or a simple format, for example with one entry per line like this (that's simply one `json.dumps(dictitem)` per line):

```
["dict1", {"key1": 1.1, "key2": 1.2}]
["dict2", {"key1": 2.1, "key2": 2.2}]
["dict3", {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}]
```

Then you can simply append an entry/line to the file, and parsing the file is also still easy. And memory-efficient.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = json.loads(line)
        ...
```

Comment: Good idea to structure the file for easy appending, if you can swing it. There's even a standard for this, [RFC 7464](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7464). I don't see the virtue in the particular array-per-line format you suggest, though. It's JSON, but the relationship between the key/dict name and value is elided. Why not an object per line e.g. `{"dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}}`? That preserves both append-ability and the object structure.

Comment: @JonathanEunice I think yours is more work, both for writing and for reading. Or can you do something as nice as `key, value = json.loads(line)`? Or creating the whole dictionary (if memory allows) from the file as nicely as `dict(map(json.loads, f))`? I'm just thinking of writing the dictionary items into the file, and dictionary items are pairs, not dictionaries themselves.

Comment: Solid point about key-value pairs. But full dictionaries aren't hard to manage, either. `d = json.loads(line)` per line, or `d = {}; for line in f: d.update(json.loads(line))` for the whole dict.

Comment: Yeah but then you have it as a dictionary. I claim that if you have a single-item dictionary, you don't want the dictionary but you want the key and the value. And I didn't say it's hard, I said it's more work. I think your whole-dict code proves me right :-)

Comment: Thx you for this suggestion, it's defenitly a good way to improve my code.

Answer (score -1):

look at this,  first get to the last character of your file after opening it and use re.sub() to substitute the last '}' with 'MyNewDic}', don't forget extra '}' at the end and extra ',' at the beginning when you substituting  :

```
>>> s = '{ "dict1": {"key1": 1.1, "key2": 1.2}, "dict2": {"key1": 2.1 "key2": 2.2}}'

>>> re.sub(r'}$',',"dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}}',s)
```

it gives this out put :

```
'{ "dict1": {"key1": 1.1, "key2": 1.2}, "dict2": {"key1": 2.1 "key2": 2.2},"dict3": {"key1": 3.1, "key2": 3.2}}'
```

Comment: You load all json in memory it's not a solution.